# Accessing LibSVM through Visual Studio 2010 and C++

Tags: visual-c++, libsvm

I am using LibSVM for my OCR app. I download the LibSVM and test it with Command Prompt and it works fine. Now i want to access libsvm train, predict and other functions through my visual c++ project. I have followed "Building Windows Binaries" instructions in LibSVM README file. Here what i did,

1. set the environment variables of VC++
2. nmake -f Makefile.win clean all

all above steps were succeeded. But still i have no idea about how to call those train, scale .. etc functions within c++. Can someone explain?  Please Help

Comment: I am on my phone right now so I can't check the code to give you the details, in any case you can see the code of svm-train.c which will give you an idea of how to do it, if you still have problem with this, let me know and I will post an example for you tomorrow.

Comment: @Pedrom - thank you very much for consideration.  I tried to add the svm.h and svm.cpp files into my project and call those functions within my project. But it doesnt recognize the svm.h file. It says can not open svm.h file. Actually i dont understand what to do after  "Building Windows Binaries" as in README file. what can i do with those svm-train.exe, svm-scale.exe applications rather than executing through Command Prompt. cant i link them with my c++ project ? plz help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to communicate with SVM through system() call .

```
system("myfile >myfile.scale");
```